# Color axis spine with multiple colors using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

Is it possible to color axis spine with multiple colors using matplotlib in python?

*Desired output style*:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `LineCollection` to create a [multicolored line](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html). You can then use the xaxis-transform to keep it fixed to the xaxis, independent of the y-limits. Setting the actual spine invisible and turning `clip_on` off makes the LineCollection look like the axis spine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

colors=["b","r","lightgreen","gold"]
x=[0,.25,.5,.75,1]
y=[0,0,0,0,0]
points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
lc = LineCollection(segments,colors=colors, linewidth=2,
                               transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), clip_on=False )
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
ax.set_xticks(x)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Could you describe what `transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform()` does? I can't seem to find `transform` property definition.

Comment: You may want to read the [transform tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html). Every artist has the transform property. The transform maps the coordinates to the canvas. Usually, you don't care too much, since you want to use data coordinates and the artists use a transData transform by default. In the case here, we don't want to have the position of the lines in y direction depending on the data coords but fix it to axes coords. `ax.get_xaxis_transform()` gives a transform that expects the x coordinate in data units and the y coordinate in axes units.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: What if one wants the line segment to be on another spine (for example 2nd y-axis spine on the right side with offset (in case there are 3 y-axis)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different solution. If you don't want to recolor the complete axis, you can use `zorder` to make sure the colored line segments are visible on top of the original axis.

After drawing the main plot:

- save the x and y limits
- draw a horizontal line at ylims[0] between the chosen x-values with the desired color
- clipping should be switched off to allow the line to be visible outside the strict plot area
- `zorder` should be high enough to put the new line in front of the axes
- the saved x and y limits need to be put back, because drawing extra lines moved them (alternatively, you might have turned off autoscaling the axes limits by calling `plt.autoscale(False)` before drawing the colored axes)

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
for i in range(10):
    plt.plot(x, np.sin(x*(1-i/50)), c=plt.cm.plasma(i/12))

xlims = plt.xlim()
ylims = plt.ylim()
plt.hlines(ylims[0], 0, 10, color='limegreen', lw=1, zorder=4, clip_on=False)
plt.hlines(ylims[0], 10, 20, color='crimson', lw=1, zorder=4, clip_on=False)
plt.vlines(xlims[0], -1, 0, color='limegreen', lw=1, zorder=4, clip_on=False)
plt.vlines(xlims[0], 0, 1, color='crimson', lw=1, zorder=4, clip_on=False)
plt.xlim(xlims)
plt.ylim(ylims)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

To highlight an area on the x-axis, also `axvline` or `axvspan` can be interesting. An example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 25, 100)
for i in range(10):
    plt.plot(x, np.sin(x)*(1-i/20), c=plt.cm.plasma(i/12))
plt.axvspan(10, 20, color='paleturquoise', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: axvspan example]