# Add horizontal line with conditional coloring

Tags: python, matplotlib

I make a `contourf` plot using `matplotlib.pyplot`. Now I want to have a horizontal line (or something like `ax.vspan` would work too) with conditional coloring at `y = 0`. I will show you what I have and what I would like to get. I want to do this with an array, let's say `landsurface` that represents either land, ocean or ice. This array is filled with `1` (land), `2` (ocean) or `3` (ice) and has the `len(locs)` (so the x-axis).

This is the plot code:

```py
plt.figure()
ax=plt.axes()
clev=np.arange(0.,50.,.5)
plt.contourf(locs,height-surfaceheight,var,clev,extend='max')
plt.xlabel('Location')
plt.ylabel('Height above ground level [m]')
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('o3 mixing ratio [ppb]')
plt.show()
```

This is what I have so far:

[image: Original]

This is what I want:

[image: Edited]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: See [Color axis spine with multiple colors using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273365/color-axis-spine-with-multiple-colors-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Intro

I'm going to use a [line collection](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection) .

[image]
Because I have not your original data, I faked some data using a simple sine curve and plotting on the baseline the color codes corresponding to small, middle and high values of the curve

### Code

Usual boilerplate, we need to explicitly import `LineCollection`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                  
import numpy as np                                                               
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
```

Just to plot something, a sine curve (x r

```
x = np.linspace(0, 50, 101)                                                      
y = np.sin(0.3*x)
```

The color coding from the curve values (corresponding to your surface types) to the `LineCollection` colors, note that `LineCollection` *requires* that the colors are specified as RGBA tuples but I have seen examples using color strings, bah!

```
# 1 when near min, 2 when near 0, 3 when near max
z = np.where(y<-0.5, 1, np.where(y<+0.5, 2, 3))                                  

col_d = {1:(0.4, 0.4, 1.0, 1), # blue, near min
         2:(0.4, 1.0, 0.4, 1), # green, near zero
         3:(1.0, 0.4, 0.4, 1)} # red, near max                     
# prepare the list of colors
colors = [col_d[n] for n in z]
```

In a line collection we need a sequence of segments, here I have decided to place my coded line at `y=0` but you can just add a constant to `s` to move it up and down.
I admit that forming the sequence of segments is a bit tricky...

```
# build the sequence of segments
s = np.zeros(101)                                                                
segments=np.array(list(zip(zip(x,x[1:]),zip(s,s[1:])))).transpose((0,2,1))       
# and fill the LineCollection
lc = LineCollection(segments, colors=colors, linewidths=5, 
                    antialiaseds=0, # to prevent artifacts between lines 
                    zorder=3        # to force drawing over the curve)                                                                 lc = LineCollection(segments, colors=colors, linewidths=5) # possibly add zorder=...
```

Finally, we put everything on the canvas

```
# plot the function and the line collection
fig, ax = plt.subplots()                                                         
ax.plot(x,y)                                                                     
ax.add_collection(lc)
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you. Is there any way to remove the vertical grey/white'ish bars so that the LineCollection looks continuous?

Comment: Re vertical bars, try with `antialiaseds=1` (or is it `antialiaseds=0`?) — otherwise you could try to add a really small ε to the _x_ coordinate of each segment end.   Disclaimer, I have tested none of the two ideas.

Comment: @Bollehenk I've checked, it's `antialiaseds=0`... I have edited the answer, I have also forced the color coded line to be drawn in the foreground using `zorder=3`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an `imshow()` with proper `extent`, e.g.:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colorbar as colorbar
import matplotlib.colors as colors

### generate some data
np.random.seed(19680801)
npts = 50
x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, npts)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, npts)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = x * np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)*100

### create a colormap of three distinct colors for each landmass
landmass_cmap=colors.ListedColormap(["b","r","g"])
x_land=np.linspace(0,1,len(x)) ## this should be scaled to your "location"

## generate some fake landmass types (either 0, 1, or 2) with probabilites
y_land=np.random.choice(3, len(x), p=[0.1, 0.6, 0.3]) 
print(y_land) 

fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.axes()
clev=np.arange(0.,50.,.5)

## adjust the "height" of the landmass 
x0,x1=0,1
y0,y1=0,0.05 ## y1 is the "height" of the landmass
## make sure that you're passing sensible zorder here and in your .contourf()
im = ax.imshow(y_land.reshape((-1,len(x))),cmap=landmass_cmap,zorder=2,extent=(x0,x1,y0,y1))
plt.contourf(x,y,z,clev,extend='max',zorder=1)

ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)

ax.plot()
ax.set_xlabel('Location')
ax.set_ylabel('Height above ground level [m]')
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('o3 mixing ratio [ppb]')

## add a colorbar for your listed colormap
cax = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.95, 0.5, 0.02]) # x-position, y-position, x-width, y-height
bounds = [0,1,2,3]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, landmass_cmap.N)
cb2 = colorbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=landmass_cmap,
                                norm=norm,
                                boundaries=bounds,
                                ticks=[0.5,1.5,2.5],
                                spacing='proportional',
                                orientation='horizontal')
cb2.ax.set_xticklabels(['sea','land','ice'])

plt.show()
```

yields:

[image: Exemplary plot now with legend]